# How can I compute a confidence interval for a sample expectation given an unnormalized distribution?

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, standard-error

Suppose I have a weight function $w(x)$ defining a probability distribution $P(x)$ for $x \in D$ as $P(x) = \frac{1}{Z}w(x)$, where $Z = \sum_{x'} w(x')$.

However, I do not know $Z$ because it is expensive to compute ($D$ is large). I only know how to compute $w(x)$ for any given $x$.

In other words, $w(x)$ represents an unnormalized version of $P(x)$.

I would like to use sampling to compute $E[f(x)] = \sum_{x\in D} f(x)P(x)$, and to obtain a confidence interval.

My question is: how can I compute an estimate and confidence interval for $E[f(x)]$ using only $w(x)$ and not computing $Z$?

Here's what I have come up with so far:

Let $g(x)$ be the statistic $f(x)w(x)$, and let $\mu_g$ and $\sigma_g$
be its mean and standard deviation.

By definition, $\mu_g = \frac{\sum_{x \in D} f(x)w(x)}{|D|}$.

I can compute an estimator $\hat{\mu}_g = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)w(x_i)} {n}$,
for $x_i \sim Uniform[D]$. By the Central Limit Theorem, $\hat{\mu}_g$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu_g$ and standard error $\sigma_g/\sqrt{n}$.

**Update**: a comment pointed out that this will work poorly with just sampling from the uniform distribution if the density is concentrated in some small region. This is true. I could instead exploit structure in $w$ and use importance sampling, or even MCMC. The issues presented here would remain, though. I believe this is a completely orthogonal topic. **End of update.**

I can define an estimator $\hat{E}[f(x)]= \frac{|D|}{Z} \hat{\mu}_g$.
Because $\hat{\mu}_g$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu_g$ and standard error $\sigma_g/\sqrt{n}$,
we have that $\hat{E}[f(x)]$ is normally distributed with mean $\frac{|D|}{Z}\mu_g$ and standard error $\frac{|D|}{Z}\sigma_g/\sqrt{n}$.

Note that, because $\mu_g = \frac{\sum_{x \in D} f(x)w(x)}{|D|}$,
$$\frac{|D|}{Z}\mu_g = \frac{|D|}{Z}\frac{\sum_{x \in D} f(x)w(x)}{|D|}$$

$$ = \sum_{x \in D} f(x)\frac{w(x)}{Z}$$

$$ = \sum_{x \in D} f(x)P(x)$$

$$ = E[f(x)],$$

so $\hat{E}[f(x)]$ is normally distributed with mean $E[f(x)]$
and standard error $\frac{|D|}{Z} \sigma_g/\sqrt{n}$.

This almost fulfills my goals; I now have an estimator $\hat{E}[f(x)]$ for $E[f(x)]$, and
its standard error, so I can compute a confidence interval.
However, the standard error of $\hat{E}[f(x)]$ depends on $Z$, which I cannot compute.

To deal with this, we can define an estimator $\hat{\mu}_w = \frac{\sum_i w(x_i)}{n}$ for $\mu_w$, which by definition is $\frac{\sum_{x \in D} w(x)}{|D|} = \frac{Z}{|D|}$. This means that $\hat{\mu}_w$ is normally distributed
with mean $\frac{Z}{|D|}$ and standard error $\sigma_w/\sqrt{n}$.

We can use $\hat{\mu}_w$ to define an estimator $\hat{Z} = |D|\hat{\mu}_w$.
Because $\hat{\mu}_w$ is normally distributed
with mean $\frac{Z}{|D|}$ and standard error $\sigma_w/\sqrt{n}$,
$\hat{Z}$ is normally distributed with mean $|D|\frac{Z}{|D|}=Z$,
and standard error $|D|\sigma_w/\sqrt{n}$.

Now, I would like to estimate the standard error of $\hat{E}[f(x)]$
by $\frac{|D|}{\hat{Z}} \sigma_g/\sqrt{n}$ (note the substitution of
$\hat{Z}$ for $Z$), so I can compute its confidence interval.
However, it seems that simply plugging $\hat{Z}$ in place of $Z$,
and ignoring $\hat{Z}$'s own standard error, seems incorrect.
I think I have to take $\hat{Z}$'s own standard error into account
and find a confidence interval for $\hat{E}[f(x)]$ that reflects
the uncertainty about $Z$. It's at this point that I'm stuck.
What do people usually do in situations like this?

(Perhaps simply pretending $\hat{Z}$ is $Z$ makes sense;
it is similar to using a sample standard deviation instead of the
true standard deviation when computing the standard error, after all).

Comment: Markov Chain Monte Carlo methods solve your problem. Your suggested approach may fail miserably if the density is concentrated in a small subset of D.

Comment: From what I understand, what you point out (sampling efficiency when the density is concentrated in a small region) is a completely orthogonal issue. I would still have the same issues computing a confidence interval even with MCMC.

Comment: I can't see what makes you say this is an orthogonal issue. Also, your normal approximation probably relies on CLT and you would need very large N to achieve normal approximation in the case of a concentrated measure. What is typically done is sampling the distribution using MCMC and giving the *sampled* confidence intervals. This only relies on assuming you have enough "independent" samples, a number which can be estimated using th markov chain's autocorrelation time.

Comment: I meant orthogonal in the sense that the question is about computing confidence interval. The choice of MCMC vs non-MCMC is a separate dimension.
Your point is well taken and makes sense, but at this point I would like to know how to compute the confidence interval in the given, non-MCMC setting given.
Also, by saying that one needs to use the sampled confidence interval in MCMC, you seems to be saying that we don't have a formal answer for the confidence interval in the MCMC setting, right? Although probably in practice that does not matter much.